# Unity3D: Failed to find a placeholder Newtonsoft.Json.dll for Newtonsoft.Json.dll', ensure it exists, or change plugin settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, build, json.net

I pulled a Unity3D project from git which already has Newtonsoft.Json.dll

When I am trying to build and run, it gives me this following error

```
    Failed to find a placeholder ('Assets/JsonDotNet/Assemblies/Standalone
/Newtonsoft.Json.dll') for 'Assets/IBMSdkCore/ThirdParty/JsonDotNet

/AOT/Newtonsoft.Json.dll', ensure it exists, or change plugin settings for

'Assets/IBMSdkCore/ThirdParty/JsonDotNet/AOT/Newtonsoft.Json.dll' 

accordingly.
```

I went through this link

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/dll-placeholder-values-cannot-be-found-when-dll-is-in-a-local-package

The solution says to configure the placeholder from the project that's referencing a package.

I am not sure how to do that. Can someone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Json.Net to a Unity3D project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398407/adding-json-net-to-a-unity3d-project)

Comment: @Ruzihm When I tried to add the reference. It says it could not be added, as "Newtonsoft.json" already exists in the project

Comment: How do I delete the existing reference to the component? It not even says Installed in Manage NuGet packages.

Comment: maybe the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36944427/1092820) will help